# Error inflating Fragment in Dialog the second time

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have the following code in an Activity that starts a dialog for a layout that contains a fragment.

```
...
case R.id.pick_resource:
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.resource_picker);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setTitle("Pick a resource");
        dialog.show();
```

This works very well the first time after application start, but when the dialog is quit and later called again, I get this stack trace:

```
08-10 10:47:33.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
        at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:449)
        at org.rhq.pocket.StartActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(StartActivity.java:118)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2390)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:852)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:956)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:174)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:85)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f090007, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for org.rhq.pocket.ResourcePickerFragement
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4089)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
        ... 24 more
```

Any idea, what may cause this exception? Do I have to unload the fragment somehow?

Comment: where did you declare "dialog" variable?check whether have you declared "dialog" as a class variable or not.

Comment: adding some more code will help us understanding the problem

Comment: @Jainal within the activity, but this does not change when I put Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Does the fragment in your layout have an android:id attribute?

I suspect this is because the fragment is instantiated each time your layout is inflated, the first time the ID isn't being used, but the second time the FragmentManager still thinks your Fragment is alive, so the ID is considered a duplicate.

Try removing the android:id attribute from your fragment if it exists, or add a placeholder layout such as a framelayout and use a fragmenttransaction to dynamically add the fragment each time your dialog is created.

Comment: Wow, I've been searching for 6 hours on why I get the duplicate ID error when I try to add/remove fragments from a container. You are a life- and sanity-saver :D Awesomness! ^^

Comment: Removing a Fragment's ID/tag works but assumes that you don't need to lookup a reference to it.  Adding the fragment programmatically (as you mentioned) is one option.  Programmatically removing it when the dialog is dismissed (e.g., in an OnDismissListener) is another.  That approach worked well for me.

Comment: THis does not work for me. If I remove the id, I get an exception: *Binary XML file line #103: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment*

Comment: Any idea why he thinks that way, when the parent is destroyed completely?

Comment: For those who have Must specify `unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for ...`, you can wrap `<fragment>` in a for example `<RelativeLayout>` and specify id for the RelativeLayout and remove any id from the fragment.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem

I solved it very easy

deleting all fragments when close dialog

This is my dialog

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="310dp"
    android:layout_height="260dp" >

     <fragment
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:tag="one"
        class="com.android.mushrooms.CookingProgressFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:tag = "two"
        class="com.android.mushrooms.CookingInfoFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and that's what happens when you delete a dialog

```
dialog.findViewById(R.id.cifButtonClose)
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDragController.endDrag();

                        FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction();

                        ft2.remove( getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentByTag("one"));
                        ft2.remove( getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentByTag("two"));
                        ft2.commit();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows

```
public class ABDCD{
    private Dialog dialog = null;
    private View viewHoldingDialog = null;
    ----------------------------

case R.id.pick_resource:
    dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    viewHoldingDialog = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.resource_picker, null);
    dialogLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.addContentView(viewHoldingDialog,


    dialogLayoutParams);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help someone:

I use the code of Эвансгелист Evansgelist, but with a DialogFragment that has a layout with a MapFragment, the code have to be onDestroy block:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    FragmentTransaction ft2 = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    ft2.remove( getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_map));
    ft2.commit();
}
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.example"
>
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map_map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: this is the right answer. I call `dismiss()` inside `onPause` then remove the fragment inside `onDismiss`

Comment: Thanks a lot @M D P. Yours solution is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
On android.view.inflateexception: binary xml file line #8: error inflating class fragment error :
```

Try removing the android:id attribute from your fragment if it exists.
and on dismiss dialog add the following code: it works for me

```
activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mMap_location)).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that could help someone else: I had a similar problem but instead of destroying the fragment in the onDestroy, I had to move it to onPause in order to get it to work:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(adFragment != null){
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(adFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```