# Error inflating Class fragment in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to create a dialogfragment with a listview inside of it and I used the accepted answer from this question to do it

[How to display an existing ListFragment in a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342032/how-to-display-an-existing-listfragment-in-a-dialogfragment)

But I am getting an `Error inflating class fragment` when I try to open the fragment dialog and the app crashes

Below is the `dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment` layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <fragment
         android:id="@+id/flContent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:padding = "10dp"
         class="com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.AndroidXMLParsingActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and it is not the androidxmlparsingactivity fragment that is causing it to fail, I have tried it with other fragments and they did not work either

Below is my dialog fragment class

```
public class BodyDialogue extends DialogFragment {
int mNum;

/**
 * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
 * as an argument.
 */
static BodyDialogue newInstance(int num) {
    BodyDialogue f = new BodyDialogue();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");

    // Pick a style based on the num.
    int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 1: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 2: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 3: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_INPUT; break;
        case 4: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        case 5: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        case 6: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 7: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 8: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
    }
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 4: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo; break;
        case 5: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog; break;
        case 6: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
        case 7: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel; break;
        case 8: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
    }
    setStyle(style, theme);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment, null);

    return view;

}
}
```

and this is how i call the dialogfragment

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                BodyDialogue  dialogFragment = BodyDialogue.newInstance(1);
                 dialogFragment .setRetainInstance(true);
                 dialogFragment .show(getFragmentManager(), "bodydialogue");
            }
```

this was the cause in the logcat

```
08-17 19:43:15.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3605): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0031, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.AndroidXMLParsingActivity
08-17 19:43:15.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3605):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
```

Comment: yes because if I just call it to replace a fragment it appears fine. Like I said, it has nothing to do with that fragment, I have tested it on other fragments and they dont work either, I added my logcat, I think you may find the solution to the problem there

Comment: Please don't prefix your questions titles with Android or any other tag, the tags at the bottom are more than enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I am getting an Error inflating class fragment when I try to open
>   the fragment dialog and the app crashes

This is happening because you use as the `BodyDialogue` fragment's view a layout which already includes another fragment(through the `fragment` tag). This will fail as nested fragments aren't allowed to be inflated from a xml layout, as [the guide for the nested fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) already mentions:

*Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a < fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.*

So if you want to embed the `AndroidXMLParsingActivity`(awful naming btw for a fragment) in the `BodyDialogue` dialog fragment then do it in code in the same `onCreateView` callback using `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: do you have an example of that?

Comment: @CamConnor Have a look at https://gist.github.com/luksprog/6265896 if you didn't yet make it yourself.

Comment: +1 "the guide for nested fragments already mentions" ... seems you're the only one that has read it :) been all night fighting with xmls+nestedfrags until I read this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this simple and easy

**Please refer to this answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966061/963591

My code using above answer

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

// TODO Auto-generated method
                                        // stub

FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                        ft2.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("one"));
                                        ft2.commit();

dialog.dismiss();

}
```

My xml

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dip"
            android:tag="one"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtTargetStreet_hint"
            android:layout_margin="20dip" />
```