# Call inflate on layout with fragment that contain com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-inflate, mapfragment

I have this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sat"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/satellite" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/traffic"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/traffic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/normal"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.24"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.92" />
```

And i need to call in my activity the inflate for get the all view of my layout.
I call

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View layout = inflater.inflate(res, null);
```

where res is the id of the layout but have this exception:

```
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{it.unisa.microapp/it.unisa.microapp.activities.MapsLocationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at it.unisa.microapp.activities.MAActivity.setAppView3(MAActivity.java:457)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    ... 11 more
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #45: Duplicate id 0x7f060011, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4751)
10-23 16:27:44.207: E/AndroidRuntime(12310):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
```

I think the problem is that i can't inflate the fragment with com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
how i can resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You can't inflate a layout in a fragment that contains a fragment. Doesn't mater the type...

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296294/562840).

Comment: how can I get around this? Is there another way to take the view of a layout without making inflate?