# App getting force close when the fragment opened for second time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I create a fragment from the xml  file and directly adding xml file in setcontentview method in activity. For the first time it was working fine, if I reopen that fragment in causing force close.

Issues in error log is

```
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591): Process: com.pal.newloginscreenui, PID: 5591
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at com.pal.newloginscreenui.DashboardActivity.display_popopMenu(DashboardActivity.java:112)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at com.pal.newloginscreenui.DashboardActivity.onClick(DashboardActivity.java:80)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f06004b, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.pal.newloginscreenui.NavigationMenuFragment
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4824)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
02-02 18:09:22.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5591):     ... 17 more
```

The xml:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/containner"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:id="@+id/frag"
   android:name="com.pal.newloginscreenui.NavigationMenuFragment" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 
</FrameLayout>
```

Popupwindow which I was calling

```
DoctorGlobal.pw = new PopupWindow(DashboardActivity.this);// create a popup window
    DoctorGlobal.pw.setTouchable(true);
    DoctorGlobal.pw.setFocusable(true);
    DoctorGlobal.pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    DoctorGlobal.pw.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) { 
                DoctorGlobal.pw.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    int popWndwidth = (int)(width/4)*3;
    DoctorGlobal.pw
            .setWidth(popWndwidth);
    DoctorGlobal.pw
            .setHeight(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    View contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navg_menu, null);
    DoctorGlobal.pw.setContentView(contentView);
    container = (FrameLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.containner);
    DoctorGlobal.pw.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0);
```

in `navg_menu` having the above xml code

Comment: Please also share the layout xml. are you using child fragments ? (e.g. a fragment within a fragment)

Comment: <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag"
            android:name="com.pal.newloginscreenui.NavigationMenuFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

Comment: no only one fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

  ....

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: 
Duplicate id 0x7f06004b, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another 
fragment for com.pal.newloginscreenui.NavigationMenuFragment
```

Your xml tags:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/containner"
  ....                                      >
<fragment android:id="@+id/frag"
    android:name="com.pal.newloginscreenui.NavigationMenuFragment" 
  ....
```

Your java:

```
View contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navg_menu, null);
```

You have `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navg_menu, null);`

It would appear either `navg_menu` id does not exist or it is a menu xml that you are trying to inflate, perhaps should be using for menus and make sure that you have a the correct id to create your contentView.;

```
`MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();`

`getMenuInflater().inflate`
```

Or there is a duplicate id that you are accessing.
Hopefully this will help you debug it.

I think this answer here will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513735/3956566

or dismissing the fragment when you are finished with it as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966061/3956566

Comment: there is no duplicate id. i was thinking the issue was that im calling fragment two times for the first time it was not getting no issue because in fragment backstack no fragments are there and i opened for second time it was throwing issue may be fragment was thier in backstack.

Comment: actually it was declared in xml file na. so iam not handling anything in java code.

Comment: yes the above example are working by removing fragment form fragment transcation. Now working fine. Thankssss